# Why is typescript upset about comparing to undefined?

Tags: typescript

```
let myVar: number | undefined;

if (100 > myVar) doSomething();
```

Typescript tells me "myVar" is possibly undefined. What's wrong with that? I know it is, I explicitly typed it as such, but it seemingly doesn't want me to put it in the comparison? I know the outcome of the comparison if the variable is undefined, in fact I'm depending on that behaviour, what does Typescript want me to do?

Comment: If you know how the code behaves, ignore the warning. TypeScript tries to steer people toward clean, understandable code. The result of `100 > undefined` being false is neither clean, nor intuitively understandable. It wants you to use something like `if (myVar === undefined || 100 > myVar) `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is typescript upset about comparing to undefined?

If `strictNullChecks` is enabled, TypeScript will enforce greater type safety. [As of early 2017](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13483), that increased type safety means it is an error if "either operand of a `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, or `in` operator is `nullable`."

> what does Typescript want me to do?

When a type is a union of `number | undefined`, TypeScript wants you to check for `undefined` before running a relational operator.

```
let doSomething = () => undefined;

let myVar: number | undefined;

if (myVar && 100 > myVar) doSomething();
```

In the case of zero being a valid falsy value, you can use one of these forms:

```
if ((myVar || 0) && 100 > myVar) doSomething();

if (myVar !== undefined && 100 > myVar) doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

You've set up a trap for the next person to edit this code, who might think that writing

```
if (myVar >= 100) {
  // Handle the other case
} else {
  doSomething();
}
```

is a valid way to refactor the code.

You could write `if (100 > myVar!)` if you wanted to pretend that `myVar` was never `undefined`, though that probably communicates an even more dangerous intent.

`if (100 > (myVar || 0))` might be a clearer way that communicates that `undefined` and `0` get the same treatment in this particular case.